How Well Should Interface Definition Match Database Table?
Would love an answer from an Angular ninja. I have a basic interface definition:
export interface Lot {
  LOT_ID: Number
  LOT_LOC_ID: Number
  LOT_TITLE: String
  LOT_DATE_INSERTED: Date
}

I can display this in a table like so:
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let lot_rec of lot_recs">
            <td>
                {{ lot_rec.LOT_ID }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ lot_rec.LOT_TITLE }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ lot_rec.LOT_LOC_ID }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ lot_rec.LOT_DATE_INSERTED }}
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>

However, I would like to show LOC_TITLE from the LOC table.
Obviously I can join LOT to LOC on LOT_LOC_ID = LOC_ID.
But do I add LOC_TITLE to the interface for LOT?

This sounds like an opinion-based question. It depends on how your back-end query data and returns the response and how the front-end receives and displays the data. If you are returning the LOC_TITLE from the joined table, adding the LOC_TITLE field to the Lot interface is straightforward. And in your backend you only need to query and return the data field that is needed without returning the whole associated entity.

If your scenario is returning the associated entity, would recommend having a property with an object/entity type that aims to easily differentiate where the data is from (base/associated entity) and avoid property names duplicating.

Besides, don't use Number and String types, but use number and string types which are the primitive types. You may get unexpected behaviour when using these Global object as types. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/number-vs-typescript-tamjid-ahmed/

I will change types. I wasn't aware.

I will have an interface for LOC as well and it will have LOC_TITLE. Is there any way to use a combination of the two interfaces for my returned records or must I duplicate LOC_TITLE in the interface definition each time I am displaying data for a table that has a FK to LOC?
